# IE popup an "object doesent support this propety o method" when using ExternalInterface.call

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, externalinterface, actionscript-3

i"m getting nuts in here.

everytime i try to do even an

```
ExternalInterface.call('alert','abc');
```

(which will work on every browser) i get an

> object doesent support this propety or method

after the alert appears.

it even happens in the HTML generated by flash without me touching it...
there is any solution?!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after 3 days! found it!
the id of the flash movie wasn't unique on the page.. that's all..